# UIGestureRecogniser key-value coding

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to use key-value coding on an `UIGestureRecogniser`. The line of code below crashes when it tries to set the value. Is `UIGestureRecogniser` compliant to the key-value coding protocol and what alternatives can be used?

```
gesture.setValue(NSValue(CGPoint: draggedObjectOffset), forKey: "draggedObjectOffset")
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key draggedObject.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not that `UIGestureRecognizer` doesn't adhere to a key value coding protocol, it's that it doesn't accept values for the key `"draggedObjectOffset"`. Key value coding is in many ways similar to `@property` statements. You can't just assign arbitrary data to arbitrary keys for objects that claim to be "key value coding-compliant".

I would suggest writing a simple subclass to accomplish this task.